# Newline in openxlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

A question on openxlsx library in R:

I'm looking for a way in openxlsx to add a newline to a cell value so that the value is in two (or more lines) in Excel. I mean similar functionality that you get in Excel by typing a value, pressing Alt-Enter and adding another value.

And no, I am not looking for a trick to do it using data frames or word wrapping with appropriate column width but something else.

For example this solution candidate doesn't work:

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(
    data.frame("I want this in two lines\nin one cell"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    file = "foo.xlsx"
)
```

Everything is still printed on one line.

Comment: Try “\n” to add a new line

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Please include a sample of your data and the code you have tried, so you can help us help you. Have you had a chance to look at the guidance about how to ask a question [ask] and to include a reproducible example [reprex]?

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I added a minimalistic example.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Seems a lot of work for something so simple in `excel` but I've found this with `openxlsx` you can do most things with a bit of effort, I really like the package.

```
txt <- data.frame(t = c("I want this in two lines", "in one cell"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", x = txt)
# to make sure your text shows as two lines
setRowHeights(wb, "Sheet 1", rows = 4, height = 30)

# this seems to force the line break to split the text over two lines
style1 <- createStyle(wrapText = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, style1, rows = 4, cols = 1, gridExpand = TRUE)

#narrow width produces multiple lines as a consequence of text wrap
setColWidths(wb, sheet = 1, cols = 1, widths = 40)

#Here's the key bit; excel does not seem to like \n as a line break an online search suggested CHAR(10) as the alternative to `alt enter` keystroke for line break in an excel cell 
writeFormula(wb, 1, x = "A2&CHAR(10)&A3", startCol = 1, startRow = 4)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "foo.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was just playing around with this problem and it looks like, (at least in some versions of excel), you can add a `\n` to specify where you want the text wrapping to occur. You still have to go through the whole process of creating a workbook, adding a style, saving the workbook, but, at least for me, it looks like it gave me a bit more control over where the line break occurs than like I would if I was just playing around with column widths to force a line break. For example:

## Make the Dataframe

We'll use data from this library

```
library(nycflights13)
```

Then we'll make a small dataframe from a subset of flights

```
example_df <- as.data.frame(flights[1:3,c(1,7:8)])
```

Then we'll make some annoyingly long column names that we want openxlsx to wrap automatically based on column width

```
names(example_df)  <- rep("Here's a really really really unnecessarily long to the point of being painful column name",3)
```

Then we'll add text to the first column and put an `\n` where want the line break to occur

```
example_df[,1] <- paste0(example_df[,1], "\n",c("Total","Total","YTD"))
```

Here's what it looks like in R

```
> example_df
  Here's a really really really unnecessarily long to the point of being painful column name
1                                                                               2013\nTotal
2                                                                               2013\nTotal
3                                                                                 2013\nYTD
  Here's a really really really unnecessarily long to the point of being painful column name
1                                                                                       830
2                                                                                       850
3                                                                                       923
  Here's a really really really unnecessarily long to the point of being painful column name
1                                                                                       819
2                                                                                       830
3
```

## Format with openxlsx package

we'll use these packages

```
library(xlsx)
library(openxlsx)
```

Then we'll write our example dataframe to excel

```
xlsx::write.xlsx(example_df, file = "example_df.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
```

Then we'll link the excel file to a workbook in R using the openxlsx package

```
n3 <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(file = "example_df.xlsx")
```

Then we'll create a style that forces excel to text wrap

```
my_style <- openxlsx::createStyle(
  fontSize = 11, 
  halign = "center",
  wrapText = TRUE
)
```

Then we'll add the style

```
openxlsx::addStyle(n3, sheet = 1, my_style, rows = 1:400, cols = 1:400, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

Then we'll set the column widths so that text wrapping happens based on the specified width

```
openxlsx::setColWidths(n3, 1, cols = 1:400,  widths = 21)
```

Then we save the workbook

```
saveWorkbook(n3, "example_df.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

## Result

[image]

That's what I ended up with. The first row wrapped based on column width and the first column wrapped where we put the `\n`. I did this on `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO 32-bit` and `Windows 10`. I hope this works for other ppl too, but knowing Microsoft, it probably won't

Answer (score 0):

```
library(openxlsx)

df<-data.frame(col1="I want this in two lines\nin one cell")

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", x = df)

style1 <- createStyle(wrapText = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, style1,rows = 1:2, cols = 1, gridExpand = TRUE)
setColWidths(wb, sheet=1, cols = 1, widths = 25)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "output.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```